# Base64 decoding error

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, character-encoding, base64

Using the Boost C++ library, I am trying to base64decode the following base64 encoded value: OTE4ZDUxYzM0ZTIyNmEzZDVmY2NjNjAyMzYyOTU5MTg0NzVmYWEwMjox  using the following code:

```
std::string base64_decode(const std::string& s) {
  namespace bai = boost::archive::iterators;

  std::stringstream os;

  typedef bai::transform_width<bai::binary_from_base64<const char *>, 8, 6> base64_dec;

  unsigned int size = s.size();

  // Remove the padding characters, cf. https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5629
  if (size && s[size - 1] == '=') {
    --size;
    if (size && s[size - 1] == '=') --size;
  }
  if (size == 0) return std::string();

  std::copy(base64_dec(s.data()), base64_dec(s.data() + size),
            std::ostream_iterator<char>(os));

  return os.str();
```

Looks like the encoding happens correctly, however, while decoding, I still get the following error: *terminate called after throwing an instance of boost::archive::iterators::dataflow_exception what(): attempt to decode a value* *not in base64 char set* at the line:

```
std::copy(base64_dec(s.data()), base64_dec(s.data() + size), std::ostream_iterator<char>(os));
```

Comment: It's not what you asked, but the encoded text is the sha1 digest of "8:1" encoded in lowercase hex, which is then base64 encoded. (don't tell me it's a password)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the reputation to comment, so this is an answer instead:

"attemp to decode a value not in base64 char set" sounds like you should verify the actual input of the function, for the given input

`OTE4ZDUxYzM0ZTIyNmEzZDVmY2NjNjAyMzYyOTU5MTg0NzVmYWEwMjox`

your code works: https://ideone.com/zWl52N

Answer (score 0):

Changing the

```
std::copy(base64_dec(s.data()), base64_dec(s.data() + size), std::ostream_iterator<char>(os))
```

to

```
return std::string( base64_dec(s.c_str()), base64_dec(s.c_str() + size))
```

resolved the issue.